# My bootstrap navbar is not expanding in mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMZSt.png)

The navbar works fine on desktop view but as soon as I check on mobile, it doesn't drop down. It seems as it tries to drop down, a small line comes but none of the links come.

```
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand logo_h" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                     aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse offset" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu_nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item submenu dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                                 aria-expanded="false">Shop Category</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="premium-executive.html">Premium Executive</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="executive.html">Executive</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="workstation.html">Workstation</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="others.html">Others</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">about</a></li>

                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: There should be more codes. You missed. Please provide all the necessary codes to get a  solution.